# Marshalling list of case class objects

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I want to return list of json objects based on my case class objects.

Following is my spray router, which returns list of 'Appointment' objects.

```
trait GatewayService extends HttpService with SLF4JLogging {

  import com.sml.apigw.protocols.AppointmentProtocol._
  import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

  implicit def executionContext = actorRefFactory.dispatcher

  val router =
    pathPrefix("api" / "v1") {
      path("appointments") {
        get {
          complete {
            val a = new Appointment("1", "2")
            val l = List(a, a, a, a)
            l
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Following is the 'AppointmentProtocol'

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol

case class Appointment(id: String, patient: String)

object AppointmentProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val appointmentFormat = jsonFormat2(Appointment.apply)
}
```

It gives the compilation error 'expression type of List[Appointment] doesn't confirms to expected type toResponseMarshallable'

Comment: can you try placing an `implicitly[JsonFormat[Appointment]]` in the router and see whether it succeeds?

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference, but why are you using `Appointment.apply` instead of simply `Appointment` in the initialization of `appointmentFormat`? Do you have explicitly declared the companion of case class `Appointment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you missed something in your example, but my brain-based compiler is telling me that your code should throw a compilation error since any directive in Spray requires a result of type `Route`, as i can see you have a `List[Appointment]`. Please read [this](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-routing/key-concepts/routes/) article on Routes. Your route structure should be completed with `complete`, so i assume the this way would solve your issue:

```
get {
  val a = new Appointment("1", "2")
  val l = List(a, a, a, a)
  complete(l)
}
```

Please note a `complete` directive which wraps the list. This should help, otherwise please provide the tree with resolved implicits by compiling your code with the flag `-Xprint:typer`, that should show where the problem with implicits is.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I already having the "complete" directive. I forgot to add it in the question.  I can return single "Appointment" object. Problem occurs when I'm trying to return List of Appointment objects.

Comment: @eranga I see. That sounds like an implicits ambiguity issue, most commonly it happens because of several imports of `DefaultJsonProtocol` into the scope, are you sure you don't have this case? If you are using IDEA you can use implicit inspector to investigate which one you'r missing, I guess the problem is in the `listFormat`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, that could be the problem. I'l try to investigate it.

Comment: Hi, that is the problem, I have imported several protocols(which are having DefaultJsonProtocol). Problem solved now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What do we do if we need to import several protocols?

Comment: @IvanBalashov You can import them, but in this case Scala compiler wouldn't be able to resolve them due to the ambiguity, so you need to use them manually / explicitly or use some type level mechanics to resolve the issue (not always applicable)

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should use this library spray-json depending on your version of spay this will be your import and do not forget to add the imports to your code:

```
import MyJsonProtocol._
    import spray.json._
```

for that be sure that you have imported:

```
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.2"
```

THen you can conver an object whith this, I also have problems having the case class in the same file but this was using testing:

```
case class Color(name: String, red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int)

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val colorFormat = jsonFormat4(Color)
}

import MyJsonProtocol._
import spray.json._

val json = Color("CadetBlue", 95, 158, 160).toJson
val color = json.convertTo[Color]
```

and the list:

```
val jsonAst = List(1, 2, 3).toJson
```

This are extracted examples from the spray-json [github project](https://github.com/spray/spray-json)

Comment: the OP is already using `spray-json`, look at the import in the last snippet of the question.